# NOT function using CPU12 processor

Tags: assembly, boolean-logic, datasheet, 68hc12

Is there a code in the CPU12 processor that provides straightforward NOT functionality?

Comment: Logical NOT is not a common microprocessor feature. I suppose it could exist on some processor, but not any those that I've ever worked with.

Comment: Jim, on a MIPS processor, there is a way to do this: slti dest_reg, src_reg, 1 is exactly equivalent to a logical not. 0 becomes 1 and all non-zero values become 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be [the datasheet](http://www.freescale.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/ref_manual/CPU12RM.pdf) you're looking for. There is no `logical NOT` available, you'll have to code it yourself.

[image: Freescale-CPU12-datasheet]

Answer (score 0):

COM, COMA and COMB look like they do what you're looking for; they calculate the one's complement for a memory location, the A or the B register, respectively.

Comment: I'm looking for a logical NOT, not a bitwise NOT. ie. I do not want 10 to become 01, i want it to become 00.